# Defining a 3D array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I tried to define a 3D array on Google Sheet, but even though I'm using the `.slice()` method it keeps passing the array by reference.

```
 var temp = [];
 for (var a = 0; a<archetypesAll.length; a++) {temp[a] = [0, a].slice();};
 var archRank = []; 
 for (var a = 0; a<21; a++) {archRank[a]= temp.slice();};
 archRank[2][1][0] = 'Test';
```

I want to edit a single element of the matrix but instead the code above just fills every row with the exact same value ('Test'):

```
3DMatrix[x][1][0] = 'Test'
```

Comment: And what is your expectation? How would you want array to be passed?
And please mind the formatting.

Comment: My expectation is that the line archRank[2][1][0] = 'Test'; only fills the element [2][1][0] with 'Test' instead of on every row

Comment: Why do you mention the words array/reference in your sentence? That's rather confusing I think.

Comment: Because I think that the temp array is passed by reference because changing it in one instance changes every instance of it in the matrix.

Comment: I got that, but are you asking to pass array differently than reference? Or you just want your problem solved? Please make that clear in your question.

Comment: The "`temp`" array is not being copied "by reference", but all the arrays *within* it are (asterisk, caveat, footnote, no such thing as "reference"). You're not slicing those, just their container.

Comment: So how do I set up my 3d matrix so that I can change individual elements [x][y][z] without affecting the others?

Comment: Re-create the "temp" array inside your second loop for each individual `archRank` (two nested loops); you need independent copies of all your arrays, starting with one shared array is a bad start.

Comment: Your approach worked, thank you very much! This behavior is very unintuitive to me. Why does it not work with my initial method/ what should I look up to understand it?

Comment: `[['a']]` is an array inside an array; `[['a']].slice()` just makes a copy of the outer `[]`, but it keeps all the values inside it as is. It's the same in the end as `var a = [], b = a`; both variables refer to the same array instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just copy a multidimensional array by calling slice at the top level, because that will not deep-copy the whole. You have to write your own `deepCopy` methid, like this:

```js
function allocate(mainDim, ...dims) {
  const result = new Array(mainDim);
  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = dims.length > 0 ? allocate(...dims) : 0;
  }
  return result;
}

function deepCopy(matrix, dims) {
  return dims > 1 ? matrix.map(row => deepCopy(row, dims - 1)) : matrix.slice();
}

function test() {
  const mx1 = allocate(3,2,2);
  mx1[2][1][0] = "Test";
  console.log(JSON.stringify(mx1));
  const mx2 = deepCopy(mx1, 3);
  mx2[2][1][0] = "Copied";
  console.log(JSON.stringify(mx1));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(mx2));
}
test();
```

Comment: Acctually, he can probably just use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([0, a]));` if that's the problem.

Comment: @Arg0n That's a short, nice and fast solution as long as he doesn't have objects as leaf nodes which shouldn't be copied.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["Test", "Test"];    
var array3d = [[array.slice(0)],[[array.slice(0)]]];
array3d[0][0][0] = "Changed";
console.log(JSON.stringify(array3d)); //[[["Changed","Test"]],[[["Test","Test"]]]]
```

Try with this instead of slice to get a new array instead of reference:

```
var temp = [];
for (var a = 0; a < archetypesAll.length; a++) {
   temp[a] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([0, a]));
}
var archRank = []; 
for (var a = 0; a < 21; a++) {
   archRank[a]= temp.slice();
}
archRank[2][1][0] = 'Test';
```